# Primeng confirm dialo, tree-table, data-table and some other components not working correctly with jhipster 5.3.4

Tags: jhipster, primeng

**Steps:**

1. Create a Jhipster app following official guide.
2. Run Jhipster module for primeng and select theme "nova-light".
3. From auto generated menu of primeng, click on confirm dialog menu under "Overlay Components".
4. Click on "Confirm"  button and appear the dialog box.
5. Click on any button on dialog box and dialog box gets hide.

**Problem:**
Even the dialog box disappear, a mask layer remains on the screen and prevents any user action like click and all

Note: There are some other components do not work as expected in this case. For example  "tree-table" and "data-table". It is hard to check each and every component. My question is:

1. Aren't jhipster 5.3.4 and primeng 6.1.3 not compatible??
2. Is there any additional steps to do after installing primeng with jhipster module??

**Note:** There is no code to share as I have not touched anything. So please before downvoting think for a second and read the steps to replicate the issue.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You should rather contact directly the authors this module as it is actively developed (last commit was few days agao) https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng Also it's not really a jhipster issue as it is not part of the core, you should also ask yourself why you want to use this module as it's just a showcase of primeng components and does not support entity generator. So it won't help you build your app, at some point you must learn primeng.

Comment: Agree  Gaël Marziou, I am going report it and also start to learn more about prineng. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that all components are working well with jhipster before I start development with it. Just trying to mitigate future problems related to compatibility between jhipster and primeng